# on click event not working with anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a script `onClick` function not working with anchor tag I don't know why I am clicking on it and nothing is happening

```
$(".addname").on("click", function() {
  var username = $(this).attr('title');
  var old = $("#contentbox").html();
  var content = old.replace(word, "");
  $("#contentbox").html(content);
  var E = "<a class='red' contenteditable='false' href='#' >" + username + "</a>";
  $("#contentbox").append(E);
  $("#display").hide();
  $("#msgbox").hide();
  $("#contentbox").focus();
});



<div id="contentbox" contenteditable="true"></div>


if($_POST)
{
$q=$_POST['searchword'];
$q=str_replace("@","",$q);
$q=str_replace(" ","%",$q);
$sql_res=mysql_query("select * from users where name like '%$q%' order by id LIMIT 5");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_res))
{
$fname=$row['name'];


?>
<div class="display_box" align="left">
<img src="user_img/test.jpg" class="image"/>
<a href="#" class='addname' title='<?php echo $fname; ?>'>
<?php echo $fname; ?> </a><br/>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

Please see my above question now as of I am adding data dynamically and the button adding dynamically is included within the dynamic data coming from the other file

Comment: is this anchor dynamically added?

Comment: Yes it is <a href="#" class='addname' title='<?php echo $fname; ?>'>

Comment: then use event delegation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: @guradio did not quite got your point

Comment: it is not duplicate I reviewed my case is totally different

Comment: use event delegation . like `$(document).on('click', ".addname", function(){` delegation the event to loaded element in DOM

Comment: check again mate if this is dynamically added this will fix your problem

Comment: try adding "e.preventDefault();"

Comment: place the code in document . ready

Comment: @guradio you were the first to help me out please post this in answer so I can accept your rock thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the code in `document . ready` or place it just before the the ending of body tag to allow the DOM to load first before loading of JS.

Comment: glad to help mate

Answer (score 2):

Try this fiddle, it works and it may help you, I also added the js for your convenience:

[jsfiddle onclik event](https://jsfiddle.net/5jczcLen/)

```
$(".addname").on("click", function() {
  var username = $(this).attr('title');
  var old = $("#contentbox").html();
  var content = old.replace("word??", "");
  $("#contentbox").html(content);
  var E = $("<a class='red' contenteditable='false' href='#'>" + username + "</a>");
  E.on("click", function() {alert('dynamic anchor clicked!')});
  $("#contentbox").append(E);
  $("#display").hide();
  $("#msgbox").hide();
  $("#contentbox").focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What might happen is that by clicking the anchor, the href gets fired, but since it's `#`, nothing will happen.

So you want to stop this default action, you can to that by using `e.preventDefault()`:

```
$(".addname").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var username = $(this).attr('title');
  var old = $("#contentbox").html();
  var content = old.replace(word, "");
  $("#contentbox").html(content);
  var E = "<a class='red' contenteditable='false' href='#' >" + username + "</a>";
  $("#contentbox").append(E);
  $("#display").hide();
  $("#msgbox").hide();
  $("#contentbox").focus();
});
```

Please note the extra `e` in `function(e)` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add you code in `document.ready` event, if not added already. Like below,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".addname").on("click", function() {
  var username = $(this).attr('title');
  var old = $("#contentbox").html();
  var content = old.replace(word, "");
  $("#contentbox").html(content);
  var E = "<a class='red' contenteditable='false' href='#' >" + username + "</a>";
  $("#contentbox").append(E);
  $("#display").hide();
  $("#msgbox").hide();
  $("#contentbox").focus();
});
});
```